# How does time in a discrete Markov Chain relate to physical time?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, stochastic-processes

Given some arbitrary discrete-time Markov Chain, is there a way to relate the time of the model to physical values in units of seconds?

For instance, I've constructed a model for diffusing particles in a box of linear size $L$. The particles have diffusion constant $D$, and there is a natural timescale arising from dimension analysis $L^2/D$. Is there a way to relate such a physical timescale to the discrete timesteps of a Markov Chain?

To be a bit more explicit, the system I consider is a box of $N$ indistinguishable particles which is divided into $R$ different compartments. The states of the Markov chain are defined by the combinations of dividing these $N$ particles into the $R$ compartments. However, I want the transition rates to depend on physical parameters of the system, including a timescale which I need to relate to the time in a Markov Chain.

Comment: [Kinetic Monte Carlo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinetic_Monte_Carlo) is designed for precisely this sort of task. It's a Monte Carlo simulation method for which the time variable corresponds to physical time.

Comment: @lemon care to make that an answer?

Comment: @lemon Thanks for the tip! This is definitely useful though it's quite different from my current model.

Comment: For my own problem I think I've found a way to relate the two by thinking of a Markov Chain as a series of snapshots of the system with some arbitrary but constant time-interval  $\Delta t$ in between them. The rates of the system can then be made dependent on this $\Delta t$, i.e. one can tune how far apart these snapshots are taken.

Comment: It is always the case that you have to build physical correctness into simulations at some level. For orbital simulations you scale your length and mass units , time step and the coefficient $G$ so that the code faithfully represents the orbits you're interested in. You have to inject *some* physical understanding *somewhere* if you want the system to represent something real. So now you ask *"How fast does diffusion/exchange/re-arrangement actually happen in the systems I care about?"*

Comment: It happens that if the random generator function increments each time a *timer*, the sequence it produces may be + or - correlated with everything. The simple incrementation may be more elaborated to take in account simultaneity. The risk of circularity is high.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$L^2/D$ is roughly the time required for your particles to have diffused over a distance $L$. You must use it as a time-scale and work in terms of non-dimensional time steps for your Markov chain: $\Delta t^*=\Delta t D/L^2$. You will want to make your time steps small, but "small" is meaningful only when you speak of non-dimensional quantities such as $\Delta t^*$. By taking a small time step in your Markov chain, you may be able to introduce some physically realistic hypotheses about how present state affects future state (one time step ahead) in your Markov chain, and thus arrive at a physically sensible transition matrix. These hypotheses that you shall introduce, will ultimately determine things such as transition rate in terms of your diffusion time scale and any other physical parameters appearing in the hypotheses.

Markov chains etc. are mathematical objects and they by themselves will not tell you anything about the physical world. Your mettle as a scientist now consists in what physical hypotheses you shall introduce to determine the transition matrix.